# Meaning of “in the way” and “as”

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

> 1) I don't know if he will do it in the way we agreed before.

This sentence means that don't know if he will treat according to things that we agree on . For example I agree with my partner on offering to low price to my customer. Although we agreed ,he said he found the price very low and would increased the price.

> 2) You must do it in the way I do

This sentence means that "you must do like I did." We are talking about way of doing something.

I wonder If my opinions are correct or not and "in the way" has two meanings

Comment: Yes . I am asking if  my explainations are correct? I mean did I understand the use of in the way correctly ?

Comment: There's only one meaning here, regardless of how it's phrased. More accurately, if ***you*** think there are two ***possible*** nuances of difference, rest assured they're both equally likely to be understood from either version. The same would apply if we used ***how*** instead of ***as*** or ***in the way***.

Comment: I just wonder if you would understand sentence the same as me. Or are there different meanings ?

Comment: I wouldn't say *I don't know if he will **do it** [as / in the way] we agreed* if what I meant was *I don't know if he will do it **for the price** we agreed*. The same would normally apply if I was unsure about the ***timing*** of the job, where I'd say *I don't know if he will do it **when** (or **on / by the date**) we agreed*. I should just add that *sometimes* people might use the ***as*** version for either/both of those senses (but it would be relatively unusual for anyone to use ***in the way*** with those senses).

Comment: If I say I don’t know if he will offer price in the way we agreed ,would  you understand me?

Comment: Yes, of course I would ***understand*** you. But I'd know you weren't a native speaker, because we'd all normally say something like *I don’t know if he will **honour / sell at**  the price we agreed* (or ***...if he will sell at / for the agreed price***).

Comment: Thank you so much.